# how to parse database error log?

Tags: java, php, parsing, error-log

I want to parse a database (MySQL, SQLite, Oracle, anyone is ok) error log to see which errors have occurred. Is there any tool available to do the job or does anyone have any idea how the job can be done using PHP or Java? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have access to the log files themselves, know the `CharSequence` (the "text") you are looking for in the log file, and want to do it with Java (e.g., SE6) read the file via a `newBufferedReader` ([Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html)), and then query the lines of the log file with `contains(CharSequence s)` ([Tutorial mentioning this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/manipstrings.html), [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)), looping through the lines.

Untested example code snippets from the top of my head:

```
    File file = full-path-to-your-file // Replace with file path
    Charset charset = Charset.forName("your-charset"); // Replace with file's charset
    try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(file, charset)) {
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.contains(error-char-sequence)) // Replace with CharSequence you're looking for
        System.out.println("Log file contains error message!");
    }
} catch (IOException x) {
    System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", x);
}
```